# Complex function bounded by rational function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

This question is from Function Theory of One Complex Variable.(Krantz and Greene)

Let R(z) be a rational function: $R(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ where p(z) and q(z) are holomorphic polynomials. Let f be holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{P_{1},...,P_{k}\}$ and suppose that f has pole at each $P_{i}$. Finally, assume that $|f(z)| \leq |R(z)|$ for all at which f(z) and R(z) are defined. Prove that f(z) is constant multiple of R(z).

My attempt:

Since $|f(z)|<|R(z)|$, the roots of p(z) are roots of f(z) and poles of f(z) are poles of R(z). This implies that q(z) has root in $P_{i}$.

Now $T(z):=\frac{f(z)}{R(z)}=\frac{q(z)f(z)}{p(z)}$. $\{P_{1},...,P_{k}\}$ is finite, then I can define $D_{i}=D(P_{i},r_{i})$ disks with radius r_{i}, centered in P and $D(P_{i},r_{i}) \cap D(P_{j}, r_{j}) = \emptyset \quad \forall i\neq j $,

In $D_{i} \backslash \{P_{i}\}$ $\frac{f(z)}{R(z)}$ is bounded. Then by Riemann removable singlularity theorem we can extend $T(z)$ for holomorphic function in $D_{i}$.

Now p(z) has roots $\{s_{1},...,s_{n}\}$. Same argument works.

Now define $H(z)$ extension of $T(z)$. H is holomorphic in whole $\mathbb{C}$ and $|H(z)|<1$, then $H(z)=C$. But, $H(z)$ restricted to $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{P_{1},...,P_{k},s_{1},...,s_{n}\}$. Then $f(z)=C R(z).$.

But there is a problem in points $\{s_{1},...,s_{n}\}$. I believe that as $\lim_{z \to s_{i}}T(z) < \infty$ implies $f(s_{i})=0$, but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Yes the solution is that $|f(z)| \le |R(z)|$ implies $T(z) = \frac{f(z)}{R(z)}$ is a bounded entire function, thus it is constant. $|f(z)| \le |R(z)|$ implies directly that $f$ has the same zeros as $R$. Also do you know how to prove Riemann's theorem on removable singularities  (hint : show that  $(z-p_1)^2 T(z)$ is holomorphic) ?

Comment: It's true. I have already written it and forget.  Thanks!

Comment: $$f(s_i) = \lim_{z \to s_i} f(z) = \lim_{z \to s_i} CR(z) =0$$

Comment: Why |f(z)|≤|R(z)| implies directly that f has the same zeros as R? Is Rouché's Theorem?